# DataTables access column by name or return extra data from server

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to make my DataTables function generic so it will work for any table on my website.

I want to colour the background of my rows depending on a 'status' column which will be present in all of my tables. The only way I can colour rows at the moment is by accessing the data array by index. I need a way to access a column by name rather than by array index.

The code below works, adding either class 'green' or 'red' depending on the value in `aData[6]` but is there any way I can look for the value in `aData['status']` instead?

php at 'https://www.example.com/table-data' returns an array:

```
return array('data' => array(...., ..., ....));
```

jQuery to initialise DataTables:

```
$('.ajax-data-table').each(function(index) {
    var table = this.id;
    // Create ajax table with datatables
    $(this).dataTable({
        processing: true,
        ajax: {
            url: 'https://www.example.com/table-data',
            data: function (d) {
                d.table = table;
            }
        },
        deferRender: true,
        responsive: true,
        columnDefs: [
            {targets: ['no-sort'], bSortable: false},
            {targets: ['no-visible'], className: 'never'}
        ],
        fnRowCallback: function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
            if (aData[6] == "W") $(nRow).addClass('working');
            else if (aData[6] == "C") $(nRow).addClass('closed');
            return nRow;
        }
    });
});
```

Another possibility may be to pass some extra data back from the server so I can tell the fnRowCallback function which column to look in for the status.

If I pass back an array from the server like `return array('data' => array(...., ..., ....), 'extra' => 6);` how would I access the 'extra' data in fnRowCallback?

### Update

I have managed to confirm I can pass back extra data from the server as above which I can see working with fnInitComplete:

```
fnInitComplete: function(oSettings, json) {
      console.log(json.extra);
}
```

Is it possible to access the json.extra data in `fnRowCallback`? If there is a way, I can use `aData[json.extra]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a bit of a hacky workaround to achieve this.

So, for anyone looking for a similar solution.....

1. Created a hidden column in your table
2. Pass back an associative array with a key of 'class' for the hidden column:
   E.g. `array('class' => 'myClass');`
3. Add the following to your datatables javascript to look for any column that has an associative array with a key name of 'class' and adds the value to the table row class:

```js
fnRowCallback: function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
      var className = $.map(aData, function(elem, index) {
          if (elem && elem.class) return elem.class;
      });
      // Add class to row
      if(className.length > 0) $(nRow).addClass(className.join(' '));
      return nRow;
    }
```